# Swift: Convert custom object using map closure

Tags: swift, closures

I have an array of Custom objects and I would like to convert them in an array of Other Custom Objects....

Can I do it with map closure?

I tried like so:

```
items.map( { (cutom: Custom1) -> Custom2 in
                Custom2(title: custom.name, locationName: custom.placeName))
            })
```

But without result...the compiler gives me the following error:
_?? is not convertible to 'Array'

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You probably mean `custom: Custom1` instead of `cutom`.

Comment: You've also got an extra ")" in the `Custom2` init

Comment: I tried to implement your code(I removed extra mark). It works.

Comment: I rollbacked the edit. @pixyzehn see: [When should I make edits to code?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/3804019)

Comment: insert a return statement into the closure or remove everything but the Custom2(...) and use $0 instead of custom: Custom1

Comment: @rintaro I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks all...there was only a conversion to do from String to double in a coordinate to use with CLLocationCoordinate2D...I didn't copied the right struct name and variables.